# Extjs - how to apply bug changes from version 6 to version 5

Tags: extjs5

[Extjs Scroll Issue](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?299046-Grid-vertical-scrollbar-jump-up-and-down-when-scrolling-from-bottom-to-top) fixed in version 6.0.1 but i need to get that changes in

Version 5.0.1. Is anyone have any Idea how to apply changes? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

The bug fix applied to source code in Ext JS 6.0.1 may have a different implementation than 5.0.1. There are only two ways to backport the fix. The first is to identify how and where Sencha fixed the bug in 6.0.1 and then adapt the changes yourself to 5.0.1 using class overrides. Alternatively, you can ask Sencha to apply the fix to 5.0.1 either in the forums or by submitting a support ticket.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-override